# Angular2 rc.6 Karma Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angular, karma-jasmine

Im new to the whole TTD with karma and jasmin, Im trying to run a test on my service which pull data from my DB, but I keep getting errors saying that ReferenceError: Can't find variable: beforeEachProviders in karma-test-shim.js here is my test below..

```
import { TracksServices } from './tracks.services.ts';

describe('Service: TracksServices', () => {

let service;
//setup
beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ TracksModule, HttpModule ],
    providers: [
      TracksServices
    ],
}));

it('get 4 featured images', done => {

    service.featured(1, 4).subscribe(x => { 

      expect(x).toContain(track);
      expect(x.length).toEqual(4);
      done();

    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

testing API in RC6 littel bit chaged.

for example changes in angular2-webpack-starter.

```
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

// Load the implementations that should be tested
import { App } from './app.component';
import { AppState } from './app.service';

describe('App', () => {
  // provide our implementations or mocks to the dependency injector
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      AppState,
      App
    ]
  }));

  it('should have a url', inject([ App ], (app: App) => {
    expect(app.url).toEqual('https://twitter.com/AngularClass');
  }));

});
```

beforeEachProvider is removed and now using TestBed.configureTestingModule()
where u should set provides: []

Comment: Thanks for the reply, managed to implement you code but now i seem to get this error PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Service: TracksServices should get customer details FAILED
        TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (near '....map(function (res) { re...') be great if you had any ideas, new to all this unit testing. thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, now resolved the issue. you were a big help, do you know any angular2 unit testing tutorials which are up to date..thanks